# SQL to select only nulls from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, null, isnull

I have a table with 260 columns, I just want to see only columns with nulls in it.
I know there are a few longer versions to see that information but is there an quicker way ?
Thanks Gurus

Comment: You mean where ALL columns are null?  or ANY column is null?  What is a "longer" versions that you want to improve?

Comment: You want a query whose result set will drop columns if the result set has no null values? Sorry. You can't get there from here. You could query the system tables (metadata) and use that to construct a query against a table whose result set only contains nullable columns, but you can't write `select *-nonnullable from foo`. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: look for a PIVOT query

Comment: Yes looking for sql that will only show columns if it has a null value. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.column_name
FROM    user_tab_columns t
WHERE   t.nullable = 'Y' AND t.table_name = 'mytable' AND t.num_distinct = 0
```

Also,before running it update your statistics:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_STATS.gather_database_stats();
END
```

Comment: SELECT  t.column_name
FROM    IP_HEADER t
WHERE   t.nullable = 'Y' AND t.IP_HEADER = 'mytable' AND t.num_distinct = 0

Error in Oracle SQL developer:
ORA-00904: "T"."NUM_DISTINCT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 71

Comment: Where did you get `IP_HEADER` from?Use it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about displaying `Nullable` table columns, look @Mihai...

You can definitely write dynamic Pl/Sql to build and execute a statement containing only columns that contain null. You can use series of loops, Ref_cursor, Execute Immediate, oracle data dictionaries, etc.

But if you would be able to, you would know already.

Regularly, you can select some data where certain values are `null`. E.g.

```
 Select * From myTable where Col1 is null or col2 is null... -- 258 more columns
```

This will return all 260 columns, `N` rows where at least one column is `Null`